# zurb foundation Semantic Markup - cannot provide parameters

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Im trying to manipulate a `sub-nav` in zurb foundation,

from `foundation 5` docs:

```
You can further customize your side nav, like so:

SCSS

.custom-sidenav-class {
  @include side-nav(
    // Border color of divider
    $divider-color: '#ccc',
    // Font size of nav items
    $font-size:1.2em,
    // Color of navigation links
    $link-color:'#ccc';
  );
}
```

Im using this in my `SCSS`, and the element **does** becomes a sub-nav,
but `Sass` gives me an error saying:

```
error: expected a variable name (e.g. $x) or ')' for the parameter 
list for side-nav
 Use --force to continue.
```

So the actual parameters are ignored.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the variables

```
.custom-sidenav-class {
  @include side-nav('#ccc', 1.2em, '#ccc');
}
```

Comment: thanks xphong. I actually ommited the "'"s from your answer and it worked. i.e: @include side-nav(white, rem-calc(50), white);